# Show id's that only contain one kind of name

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Here is a table which will help me to explain the question.

```
    id  | name
    ----|--------------
    1   | John
    1   | John
    1   | Arya
    2   | Tyrion
    2   | Tyrion
    3   | Jamie    
    3   | Cersie
```

I need to make a SQL query that only shows id 2 because it only contains one kind of name. 
1 and 3 will not be shown because they have 2 different names. 
1 would have been shown if Arya would have been John, because then 1 would only contain Johns.

Comment: You should probably learn SQL. SQL could solve this problem easily.

Comment: What did you try so far ? Looks like something like count(distinct(name)) group by id could do the trick ?

Comment: It has to be a SQL query btw, forgot to mention it.

Comment: This is part of a larger query, and i tried to solve it myself but havent found anything worth metioning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `id` - the column you want to be unique. Then take only those groups having **one distinct** `name`

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having count(distinct name) = 1
```

Comment: `count(distinct` is really great for mining such these info

Comment: thanks, have been trying to find solution something for over an hour.